# How to identify specific code/javascript snippet & remove it

Tags: javascript, debugging, drupal, adsense

I am working with this site www.learners.ws/news, finding my way slowly & steadily. I need some help . If you take a look at this [node](http://learners.ws/news/node/47) using Firefox, you will notice that there is a green image showing in header region at the top (just above where article starts) & at the bottom just above the comments. This images appear as red-x in IE.
These started appearing after I enabled Google Adsense & Adsense injector module for Drupal.
Can anybody help me getting rid of those images, please?
P.S. I used firebug & could not locate the html.js file :(.
Please provide as detailed instructions as possible.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the images missing are:

```
<img src="/news/sites/all/themes/drupalmagazine/images/related-post-img.jpg" style="border: solid 2px #d4d4d4;">
```

At least, that is what my Chrome "inspect element" is telling me, doesn't like it has anything to do with javascript.

Comment: Gnur, I have looked at specific folder & you are right, there is no image in the folder "related-post-img". Having said that, I dont want this image to populate & want to get rid of that code completely. How?

Comment: @safaraz: Remove the line I posted from your template or source :)

Comment: Well, may be I just need a break :).I was having difficulty finding that code. I was looking for node.tpl & page.tpl, while it was in block.tpl.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Found the code in block.tpl & removed it, that resolved.